# Load specific URL in JavaScript when using OBJLoader/Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, three.js

I have a problem using a bit of JavaScript from the three.js OBJloader. I must say that I don't have that much experience and are just starting with JS and PHP for my WordPress websites.

By using the setPath and load functions I try to set the path OBJ and MTL file location. You can see this in the code underneath. However, the output for this code is "http://domain.com/product/cherries/wp-content/uploads/obj" while I want it to be "http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/obj". This is probably because the script is loaded on "/product/cherries/".

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

```
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

                var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setPath( '/wp-content/uploads/obj/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'male02_dds.mtl', function( materials ) {

                    materials.preload();

                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.setPath( '/wp-content/uploads/obj/' );
                    objLoader.load( 'male02.obj', function ( object ) {

                        object.position.y = - 95;
                        scene.add( object );

                    }, onProgress, onError );

                });
```

Just found out that this goes wrong for all URL's in this script (OBJ MTL DDS). They al point to the location where the script opens (/products/cherries/) but I want them to point to domain.com/wp-content/uploads/obj

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mtlLoader.setPath( '../../wp-content/uploads/obj/' );
```